# How to avoid save conflicts when edit item hierarchy in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, list-item, save

Developing Sharepoint 2013 portal, I met the problem of saving conflicts, caused by rapidly item updates by several users. Yep, i know about versioning and checkin/checkout, but situation gets harder because, editing one item, user indirectly updates fields of all related items hierarchy. Making item checkout will cause all range of related items to get uneditable, that is unacceptable.

Is anyone faced this problem? I need your help